# Can you initialize dynamic object using Typescript type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a readonly array of objects. Im using the Utility types of typescript to extract a field from it. Can i use the extracted union type to dynamically initilize a object?

```
type RawId = Pick<Extract<Item, {type: 'raw'}>, 'id'>['id'];
// type RawId = "id1"|"id2"|"id3"
type test = {[key in RawId ]: number};
// type test = {
//     id1: number;
//     id2: number;
//     id3: number;
// }
```

Can i use those generated types to initialize all the values to 0?

```
const initialValue: test = {
    // This does not work
    [key in keyof typeof RawId ]: 0
}
```

The Item list that the extraction is based of can be hundreds of elements long so doing it all manually would be very cumbersome, so im hoping there is a way to initiialize this programmatigaly.

Item is defined as follows

```
const items = [
{
   id: "id1",
   type: "raw"
},
{
   id: "id2",
   type: "raw"
},
{
   id: "id3",
   type: "raw"
}
] as const

type Item = typeof items[number]
```

Comment: What are `RawResourceId` and `Item`?  But you cannot use  `[key in keyof typeof` to generate typescript. The only TypeScript that emits code is `enum`.

Comment: @RuanMendes fixed the naming and added Item definition

Comment: Why not just map over `items`? https://tsplay.dev/WYLO2m

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can with vanilla TypeScript. I am using this TypeScript AST transformer:

https://github.com/janjakubnanista/ts-reflection

Example from README:

```
import { valuesOf } from 'ts-reflection';

type ButtonType = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'link';

// You can use valuesOf utility to get all the possible union type values
const buttonTypes = valuesOf<ButtonType>(); // ['primary', 'secondary', 'link']
```

More information about transformers: https://github.com/itsdouges/typescript-transformer-handbook